# Spark URL Usage: hostname vs IP address

Tags: url, apache-spark, hostname

I meet a strange issue and I am not sure whether it is a Spark usage limitation or a configuration issue.

I run Spark 1.5.1 in standalone mode. There is only one node in my cluster. All services status are ok. While I visit the Spark web address, the Spark URL is `spark://c910f04x12.pok.test.com:7077` and I can successfully submit job and start remote Spark shell with the URL and then I change the host long name to the IP address: `spark://10.4.12.1:7077` but failed. And then, I check the master output, it caused by message dropped by akka

```
16/02/22 10:55:06 ERROR ErrorMonitor: dropping message [class akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage]
for non-local recipient [Actor[akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.4.12.1:7077/]]
arriving at [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.4.12.1:7077]
inbound addresses are [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@c910f04x12.pok.test.com:7077]
```

And then, I stop the service and set the `SPARK_MASTER_IP` to `10.4.12.1` in `spark-evn.sh` and then start the service, I found the spark URL change to `spark://10.4.12.1:7077` and then I can successfully submit job with the URL of IP format but if I change to host name, the submission will be failed again. And the log similar just change the host name to IP.

So, is it my usage error or a usage limitation in Spark, the URL must be exact same string but not replaced by IP or hostname?

BTW, I use the nslookup to test my hostname and IP, the result is right. And I also try to add a long name and IP mapping in the `/etc/hosts` but there is no any help.